# Interpreting viewshed results attribute table

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, viewshed

Using QGIS Viewshed Analysis plugin I've run an intervisibility analysis (with 5km buffer) on one point against 218 others and its produced the table below. Each of the 218 points has a unique code assigned to it, however on the attribute table below I cannot see easily on the table is what the code of the unique points are that are visible.

How can I create an attribute table with the unique code?

[image]

Comment: Is there no common id field that you could join the result table to the original layer/attribute table  (what about spatially joining)?

Comment: My data had the X Y references and the unique code. 
So the single point file would have read:
X           Y           Unique Code
123456,789012, ABC1

The multi point file with 208 records was, for example:
123456, 789012, ABC1
456123, 678345, ABC2
758493, 192837, ABC3 

So there are unique code and the unique code in the single point file would also appear in the mulit point file.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Target column refers to the row in the CSV document. So the first one in the table above, where the Target is 195, refers to row 195 in the CSV sheet.